# spawn doesn't show any response

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, spawn

I'm trying to do a series of interactive commands in `node`.
The first command I want to run is `lftp` and when it will returned continue with a few more.
The problem is I'm not seeing any response. Here is my code

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var lftp = childProcess.spawn("lftp");

lftp.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

    lftp.stdin.write("This is a test to see if something changes");    //it doesn't

    lftp.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

    lftp.on('close', function (code)  {
        console.log('child process exited with code: ' + code);
});
```

But `stdout.on()` is never activate. I played with the `spwan` parameters a lot and in some cases I got the `stderr.on()` to be called but never `stdout`. When I run the `lftp` command from `shell` I get:

```
   $ lftp
   lftp :~>
```

I couldn't find any similar problems so I guess I'm doing something wrong, question is what is it?

Comment: What happens when you execute `lftp < /dev/null` from the shell directly?

Comment: nothing (like when you press `Enter`)

Comment: You don't get a prompt like you got when you run it as plain `lftp` from the shell? In that case, it might be checking if it's connected to a TTY, and if so, present a prompt (and do "something else" in other case, like when you redirect a file to it, or start it from a Node app).